# Any better practice than collecting IDs from GROUP_CONCAT results and running a second query to get one-to-many data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, one-to-many

Often, i have to write SQL queries according to the following pattern:

```
SELECT A.*, GROUP_CONCAT(B.b_id SEPARATOR ';') b_list
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.a_id
GROUP BY A.a_id
```

There exists a one-to-many relationship; one A can have multiple Bs.
Now I want to list all the As and for each of them print the list of all Bs assigned to it at the same time.

My problem is that I want to display all the columns of B as well, and to get them I need to run an extra query fetching the data for all the b_ids which appear in one of the b_lists in the result set. To achieve this, I used to iterate over the result set two times: First, I collect all the b_ids needed, after that I run a second query `SELECT * FROM B WHERE b_id IN(...collected b_ids...)` and save the result to an associative array with the b_id as the key. Next, I can easily iterate over the result set again and print the data by accessing my array containing the B columns.

Is there any better practice to achieve that? Of course I could join all the columns in the first query without the GROUP BY, but in general, my A and B tables are quite complex and I want to avoid redundancy that is caused by the A columns being "copied" for each B.

Comment: To my way of thinking, there is (almost) no problem for which GROUP_CONCAT is the answer, especially when you're running the query through application code.

Comment: Yes, that's also how I feel about it whenever I'm using it.

Comment: Good, so you know the answer to this now?

Comment: I'm not sure... would you prefer the redundant join method? I was trying to find a way to prevent the SQL server from sending the left table data multiple times because it is really much.

Comment: I don't see the redundancy ?!?! Or rather, I don't perceive that as redundancy.

Comment: I mean the temporary "redundancy" that exists in the result set if I join table B to table A. In this case the SQL server has to send the data for A multiple times, namely count(B.*) times despite it's only needed once.

Comment: Without knowing more about your tables it's hard to answer for certain, but in general that kind of 'redundancy' is irrelevant (in terms of performance)

Comment: Okay, I'll have to do some benchmarks but I was really worried about that in the first place. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the columns that you want into the `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT A.*, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', '(', B.b_id, B.col1, b.col2, ')') SEPARATOR ';') as b_list
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B
     ON B.a_id = A.a_id
GROUP BY A.a_id;
```

This will give you comma-separated values in parentheses, separated by a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks, I'll fall back on that if my clean join solution won't pan out.